# Mailshot or Newsletter?

Tags: terminology, email, programming

I'm developing a web based application that allows people to send email to many customers, for advertisement purposes.

What's the correct name for that? **[newsletter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newsletter)** or **[mailshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailshot)**?

**EDIT**: to avoid unnecessary answers like "spam" please note that customers subscribe to the service first.

Comment: I've never heard of 'mailshot' before and it's nit in the dictionary. It sounds like a made up marketing term.

Comment: @Mitch: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mailshot -- this doesn't even call it "chiefly British" though.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: it says just plain 'British' right under the word at the top.

Comment: My company calls newsletters that are e-mailed to subscribers e-newsletters. (And we call mass e-mailings promoting one thing or another e-mail blasts; at least that's what we call them internally.)

Comment: **e-mail blast** is what it is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applications that do this usually call it an **(email) newsletter**:

[MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/why-mailchimp/):

> MailChimp is the best way to send email **newsletters**

[Constant Contact:](http://www.constantcontact.com/email-marketing/what-is-email-marketing/index.jsp)

> Email **newsletters** are fast and inexpensive to create.

[Mad Mimi](https://www.madmimi.com/):

> Mad Mimi is the simplest way to create branded, well-designed **newsletters** and promotions

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia calls it [email marketing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_marketing#Email_Marketing), which is a subset of direct marketing.

> Direct marketing seeks to drive a specific "call to action." For example, an advertisement may ask the prospect to call a free phone number or click on a link to a website.
>   ...
>
> #### Email Marketing
>
> Sending marketing messages through email or Email marketing is [a] direct-marketing method.

Of course, if the advertisement is [opt out](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/opt?q=opt+out#opt__4) rather than opt in then it might be fair to call it [spam](http://catb.org/jargon/html/S/spam.html), since it could well be unsolicited.

> To mass-mail unrequested identical or nearly-identical email messages, particularly those containing advertising. Especially used when the mail addresses have been culled from network traffic or databases without the consent of the recipients. Synonyms include UCE, UBE. As a noun, ‘spam’ refers to the messages so sent.

Comment: -1 (even if i can't downvote yet). Seriusly, i know what spam is. Mine It's just a service to inform people about new products. Not thousands of email sent at the same time.

Comment: If it looks like a duck and sounds like a duck.

Comment: I am also looking for a less pejorative answer. I haven't seen one yet.

Comment: Sorry to all those who upvoted *spam*.

Answer (score 1):

Searching my email I only have one message using mailshot, and it's used as part of a URL rather than in English text.

Searching for newsletter it simply says there are hundreds of them.

Use newsletter.

Answer (score 0):

**What is an email blast?**

> **In the simplest form, an email blast (e-blasts) is a mass email sent
> to many recipients at once. This is often some promotional offer or
> any other marketing-related email a business sends to its subscribers.**
>
> Email blasting has been around pretty much as long as emails
> themselves. However, over time e-blasts evolved into more specific
> terms like email newsletters, broadcast email, and other types of
> email names.

[e-mail blast](https://mailtrap.io/blog/email-blast/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20simplest%20form%2C%20an,exclusively%20for%20digital%20marketing%20purposes.)

Not a newsletter or mailshot.